# Not getting expected correlation values - R cor()

Tags: r, correlation, pearson

I was getting all NA values except for the diagonal entries while finding correlation using R's `cor()`. I removed NAs pairwise. When I explicitly removed the NAs then I got the desired results. Have I misunderstood the arguments?

I tried

```
> c <- Result_table[,.SD,.SDcols=c("organic_account_countsession", "organic_account_countsession")]
> b <- cor(c, use="pairwise.complete.obs")

                             organic_account_countsession organic_account_countsession
organic_account_countsession                            1                           NA
organic_account_countsession                           NA                            1
```

Also tried this

```
> b <- cor(c, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Still got the same result.

Only when I do

```
c <- c[complete.cases(c)]
b <- cor(c)

                             organic_account_countsession organic_account_countsession
organic_account_countsession                            1                            1
organic_account_countsession                            1                            1
```

I get all 1s.
I expect to get all 1s as I am finding the correlation of a variable with itself.

(Note : The variable has variance, NA is not due to no variance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a different error altogether on my part.

I have imported the `h2o` package along with the `stats` package. 
Turns out there is a `cor()` function in `h2o` as well with a different behavior.

```
cor <- stats::cor
```

solved the problem.